# Can I create a horizontal list in HTML using only inline style

Tags: html

I am trying to create an ordered horizontal list in HTML, but I am not able to use a separate CSS file, or edit the head tag. This is because my content is part of a content management system. When, I look for how to create horizontal lists online, all solutions seem to have external CSS file, or style block in the head.

Here is what I worked my way towards, which gives a horizontal list, but doesn't number/enumerate the items:

```
<ol style="list-style: none" type="a">
    <li style="padding: 10px; display: inline">Eggs</li>
    <li style="padding: 10px; display: inline">Milk</li>
    <li style="padding: 10px; display: inline">Cheese</li>
</ol>
```

Can you help?

Edit in response to the comments: When I asked for no-CSS, I didn't realise that the style tag inline with the HTML tag counted as CSS. My rephrased question would be "How do I do this with online inline style tags".

Comment: Since you're able to use the style tag you can use css. Or not?

Comment: list-style: none is what's removing the numbers. If you want a custom counter you'll need external styling (you can't inline style pseudo elements). Even though it's invalid HTML you could just use a style element and create a custom class.

Comment: You know that `style` tag just has the CSS proprieties for the tag... You can just use the CSS code in the examples but copy the code from the selector blocks to all the items/main `ol`.

Comment: @NielsNet I can use inline style tags, but I don't have access to the <head>...</head> tag as I am writing HTML into an editor that puts my HTML into some wrapper HTML. The system is Moodle (for university content management).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of quirky thing. You need to use float to get the decimal list style to work.

```
<ol>
    <li style="float:left;">Eggs</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 30px; float:left;">Milk</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 30px; float:left;">Cheese</li>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</ol>
```

Obviously just adjust the style to your liking.

Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5dnmrdr/

Comment: Both this solution and bhansa's seem to work for me, and keep the auto-numbering which was what I was hoping for. I have opted for this one as there is a more consistent style across all list items which will make maintenance easier. Can I ask what the clear:both bit does?

Comment: @pandamonium clear both clears the effects of float on both sides (left, right). That way there shouldn't be any side effects on following html elements.

By the way. Please mark an accepted answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, use `float` and give spacing between elements:

```html
<ol style="display:inline-block">
    <li style="float:left; margin-right: 10px; ">Eggs</li>
    <li style="float:left; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 20px; padding-left: 2px">Milk</li>
    <li style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; padding-left:2px">Cheese</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **None CSS based solution**

That Would be to use elements that by default has `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`, You can't make changes to an element structure without any CSS.

```html
<span>Eggs</span>
<span>Milk</span>
<span>Cheese</span>
```

If your goal is to keep the numbering then, maybe add them yourself. other than that it's impossible to achieve with no CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and you did respond to my initial request for no-CSS. However, this was based on me not understanding how to phrase my question perfectly. The auto-numbering is quite useful for me, as it limits maintenance issues.